# negative binomial distribution unbiased estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

I have a question about the negative binomial distribution. Say, $P(X=x)= \dbinom{x-1}{M-1} p^M (1-p)^{x-M}$. I already found that  $\hat{p}=\dfrac{M - 1}{X - 1}$ is an unbiased estimator, but I got stuck while trying to find $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{p})$. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your unbiased estimator is incorrect. 

If you think its correct, you can use the Cramer Rao lower bound.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not unbiased? I do believe E\hat{p}=p, by manipulating it as p \sum pmf of M-1 H in X-1 trials. Thanks!

Comment: @user371530 : The Cramer--Rao lower bound cannot always be reached.  Is there a reason to think it is in this case? And even when it can be attained there may be some unbiased estimators that attain the lower bound and others that don't.